# Error when loading Jasperreports server

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, jasperserver, spring-ldap

I've configured LDAP authentication on Jasper reports using `default_master.properties`, `applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml`and `js.externalAuth.properties`. When I try to load jasperreports, I HTTP Status 404. Here is the stack trace.

```
2016-07-07 14:56:59,572 ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-2:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyAuthenticationProcessingFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapAuthenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' of type [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' of type [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' of type [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator#186febb8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:277)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.parse(DistinguishedName.java:224)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.<init>(DistinguishedName.java:174)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.setBase(AbstractContextSource.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.<init>(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.java:67)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource.<init>(JSLdapContextSource.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImplTokenManager.getNextToken(DnParserImplTokenManager.java:678)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.jj_ntk(DnParserImpl.java:264)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.attributeTypeAndValue(DnParserImpl.java:83)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.rdn(DnParserImpl.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.dn(DnParserImpl.java:23)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.parse(DistinguishedName.java:218)
```

Below is the `applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- ############ LDAP authentication ############
      - Sample configuration of external authentication via an external LDAP server.
    -->

    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.EncryptionAuthenticationProcessingFilter" parent="authenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager">
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="externalAuthSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="ldapAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="externalAuthSuccessHandler" />

        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/services"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager">
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="externalAuthSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/rest/login"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyRequestParameterAuthenticationFilter"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.ExternalRequestParameterAuthenticationFilter" parent="requestParameterAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager">
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="externalAuthSuccessHandler"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.JrsExternalAuthenticationSuccessHandler" parent="successHandler">
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer">
            <ref local="externalDataSynchronizer"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyBasicProcessingFilter"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalAuthBasicProcessingFilter" parent="basicProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="ldapAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationManager" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.JSProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <ref bean="${bean.daoAuthenticationProvider}"/>
                <!--anonymousAuthenticationProvider only needed if filterInvocationInterceptor.alwaysReauthenticate is set to true
                <ref bean="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"/>-->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSBindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg><ref local="ldapContextSource"/></constructor-arg>
                <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSDefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg index="0"><ref local="ldapContextSource"/></constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg index="1"><value></value></constructor-arg>
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="title"/>
                <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(uid={1})"/>
                <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
                <!-- Can setup additional external default roles here  <property name="defaultRole" value="LDAP"/> -->
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.wrappers.spring.ldap.JSFilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value></value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <value>(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0}))</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2">
            <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="searchSubtree">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapContextSource" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="${external.ldap.url}"/>
        <!-- manager user name and password (may not be needed)  -->
        <property name="userDn" value="${external.ldap.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${external.ldap.password}"/>
        <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- ############ LDAP authentication ############ -->

    <!-- ############ JRS Synchronizer ############ -->
    <bean id="externalDataSynchronizer"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalDataSynchronizerImpl">
        <property name="externalUserProcessors">
            <list>
                <ref local="externalUserSetupProcessor"/>
                <!-- Example processor for creating user folder-->
                <!--<ref local="externalUserFolderProcessor"/>-->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractExternalProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.AbstractExternalUserProcessor" abstract="true">
        <property name="repositoryService" ref="${bean.repositoryService}"/>
        <property name="userAuthorityService" ref="${bean.userAuthorityService}"/>
        <property name="tenantService" ref="${bean.tenantService}"/>
        <property name="profileAttributeService" ref="profileAttributeService"/>
        <property name="objectPermissionService" ref="objectPermissionService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="externalUserSetupProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.ExternalUserSetupProcessor" parent="abstractExternalProcessor">
        <!--Default permitted role characters; others are removed. Change regular expression to allow other chars.
                    <property name="permittedExternalRoleNameRegex" value="[A-Za-z0-9_]+"/>-->

        <property name="userAuthorityService">
            <ref bean="${bean.internalUserAuthorityService}"/>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultInternalRoles">
            <list>
                <value>ROLE_USER</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="organizationRoleMap">
            <map>
                <!-- Example of mapping customer roles to JRS roles -->
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>ROLE_ADMIN_EXTERNAL_ORGANIZATION</value>
                    </key>
                    <!-- JRS role that the <key> external role is mapped to-->
                    <value>ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>       
</beans>
```

Comment: Which lines of xml configuration did you change? The stack trace says clearly that you have $..something which does not work as Distinguished Name -DN

Comment: @BorisTreukhov- I've edited my original post with the changes I made to the xml configuration. Thanks.

Comment: upd what ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders should do? I'm not sure it does even exist in DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource .

Comment: @BorisTreukhov - I've removed ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders and edited the stack trace. Please take a look at it. Thanks, again.

Comment: How do you supply `$(external.ldap.username)` property?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov- I've `'js.externalAuth.properties'` file which contains:`external.ldap.url=${external.ldapUrl}
external.ldap.username=${external.ldapDn}
external.ldap.password=${external.ldapPassword}` and default_master.properties which has below settings external.ldapUrl=ldap://xyz:389/dc=abc,dc=local
external.ldapDn=cn=Test,ou=System Accounts,ou=CS Users,dc=abc,DC=local
external.ldapPassword=Test123

Comment: Your property file is not processed by Spring - that's all(placeholders are not replaced by values of other property file). Only xml files of Spring configuration are processed - processing is not recursive.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov-Thanks for your help. How can I make spring process my property file. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with just puttting required values into .property files instead of using placeholders?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov- When I try to put required LDAP values in the `applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml` it works. The reason behind putting ldap values in the `js.externalAuth.properties` is to encrypt the the ldap credentials later. Any thoughts?

Comment: What values are you putting into js.externalAuth.properties? In the comment above you are stating that you are putting placeholders and not the actual properties to the .properties file.